# Animate with AngularJS from one state to another state within an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, css-animations

A simplified version of the issue I'm encountering: I have a list of items in an array that are displayed with an Angular view using ng-repeat, like...

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div class="bar" ng-style="{'width': item.percent + '%'}">{{item.percent}}</div>
</li>
```

With some CSS to make it look like a bar, and hopefully animate the width...

```
.bar { 
    height: 1em;
    background: blue;
    transition: width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Every so often I update the entire `items` array with new data, which changes the `percent` value. I would like the width of the bar to animate from the previous percent value to the new one, but it seems that the `ng-repeat` is causing the entire list to be redrawn, so it's losing it's previous style and the `transition` animation is never happening.

I have looked into other solutions but they seem to only handle entering/leaving, and not changing. How can this animation happen only using Angular and CSS?

Comment: How do you update the items array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using "track by" so that the nodes aren't recreated each time?

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
    <div class="bar" ng-style="{'width': item.percent + '%'}">{{item.percent}}    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you! More information on `track by`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have some unique identifier property in your "item" you probably should track by that property instead of $index